# Codeigniter controller class

Tags: php, codeigniter, shopping-cart

I am using codeigniter to create a shopping cart.

I have created the add to cart button inside every product and a controller for adding to cart. The form's action for this button looks like that:

```
echo form_open('controller/function');
```

and the controller function:

```
function add() {
// Set array for send data.
 $insert_data = array(
        'uniqueId' => $this->input->post('uniqueId'),
        'title' => $this->input->post('title'),
        'price' => $this->input->post('price'),
        'qty' => 1
    );      

    // This function add items into cart.
    $this->cart->insert($insert_data);

    // This will show insert data in cart.
    $this->load->view('shopping_view');
}
```

However, instead of loading the shopping_view after the button click, it redirects me to this url www.url.com/controller/function where the page is not found.

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: Please post your code completely i mean controller and shopping_view

Comment: Make sure your controller file has the first letter **only** of file name and class upper case example `Shopping.php` and `class Shopping extends CI_Controller {}`

Comment: Check you have set your base url if your using CI3

Comment: Well, the controller has his first letter with uppercase and my base_url ise set

Answer (score 0):

You should include your base url as well in form_open helper function.

```
echo form_open(base_url().'controller/function');
```

Comment: It does exactly the same.

Comment: How about this? echo form_open(base_url()."/controller/function");

Comment: It happens the same. I dont think this is the problem. If I inspect the element, it seems that it reads correctly the path to the controller. The problem is that instead of loading the view that I ask inside the controller function, it redirects me to a not found url

Comment: What is your controller class name?

Comment: The controller name is Shopping

Comment: Name your controller some thing else

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117193/discussion-between-gm-akbar-and-sofiakol).

Comment: Can you inspect element the form action and show me that?
It should be like http:yourdomain/controller/function

Comment: Url should start with http

Comment: It does in inspect.